# J2ME Form Layout

Tags: java, forms, user-interface, java-me

I'm trying to make a menu like shown below. I have some items that extends CustomItem and consists of an Image and some Text. Now I want to position them as shown, but run into problems doing so - it seems only some minimal layout directives can be used in a Form. Is there a way for custom positioning using the Form class or is there another class I could use?

[image]

Comment: I'm failing to understand why you want to use form there. You have set of images that I presume will act as redirect to next screen. If this is your scenario then you do not need to use Form just go with CustomItem or with Canvas(if you will more comfortable with it). In case that you aim to do something else please explain in more details.

Answer (score 1):

Make a *HorizontalLayout* CustomItem that aligns everything that is added to it horizontally.

Details:
Such class should have some kind of array to store all the items, and when there is a request to draw it, it should ask the width of each element inside it, do some calculations and call the items' draw method. Of course, such stuff is rather difficult. You would also have to implement the selection of these items with left/right keys...

It may be slightly better to use Canvas.